# when a steam is being liquified, does its temperature change or not?

Tags: thermodynamics

Here is a question: When ice is being melted, its temperature doesn't change. So, when a steam is being liquified, does its temperature change or not? And is the heat transferred here calculated by Q=LM?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/176985/37364

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temperature at the boiling or condensation point remains the same for gas and liquid.
100 degrees Celsius for water at standard conditions.  L called the Latent (meaning hidden)
Heat of fusion times the mass of Water vapor, m, equals Q the Heat released.

Answer (score 0):

The transition from solid to liquid, from liquid to vapor, and back again, are phase changes.  Temperature change is discontinuous at a phase change.  There is no temperature change at that point.